# ssh - allow user some root functions

Tags: ssh

Does anyone know how I can allow an SSH user to execute some functions such as restarting httpd?

I'm trying to allow a user (apache) to execute some functions such as "service httpd reload" since it's not allowed. I don't really want to give apache root access, just some functions.

Comment: You might want to take a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811878/php-exec-issue/6812825#6812825

Answer (score 4):

[sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo). You can configure specific commands a user is allowed to execute in [/etc/sudoers](http://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers). Be careful when authorizing a user to run commands as root; it's easy to accidentally allow them to do more than you intended.